# Python lxml using xi:include with multiple Xml fragments

Tags: python, lxml, xinclude

I am developing a simple xml logfile class using lxml in Python.

My approach so far has been to use two files. A well-formed XML file which includes a second file which is a XML fragment. I am using an xi:include element. This way XML fragment can be updated efficiently by simply appending `<event>` elements to the end of the file.

The well formed XML file ('logfile.xml') looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<logfile>
<event xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="events.xml"/>
</event>
</logfile>
```

The xml fragment ('events.xml') looks like this:

```
<event>
     <data></data>
</event>
<event>
     <data></data>
</event>
<event>
     <data></data>
</event>
```

My goal is to end up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <logfile>
    <event>
         <data></data>
    </event>
    <event>
         <data></data>
    </event>
    <event>
         <data></data>
    </event>
 </logfile>
```

In python I am using the xinclude method to process the xi:include element in my well formed XML file ('logfile.xml'). This works **but** only if there is one `<event>` element is the XML fragment ('events.xml')

My python code:

```
tree = etree.parse('logfile.xml')
tree.xinclude()
root = tree.getroot()
print etree.tostring(self.logfileNode, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

The error I am seeing:

```
lxml.etree.XIncludeError: Extra content at the end of the document
```

I could contain the events in another element, but this doesn't lend itself well to appending data to the end of the XML fragment document.

Comment: try doing this- add <document> tag in beginning of the events.xml file, than add </document> tag in the end of file. may be this can help

Answer (score 3):

The document referenced by `xi:xinclude` *must be* a complete xml document ("complete xml infoset"). Your `events.xml` is not a valid xml document because you don't have a single root containing element.

You might be able to include just a subset by using the `xpointer` attribute to select the event elements. I'm not sure lxml supports this attribute, however.

Comment: The `xpointer` attribute _is_ supported by lxml, but it won't help, because the OP wants the "events" file to be an xml fragment. But as you rightly say: it just can't be.

Comment: But he *could* add an `events` root to events.xml and then include with something like `<xi:include href="events.xml" xpointer="xpointer(/events//event)" />`, right?

Comment: He says he wants to append `<event>` elements _directly_ to the end of `events.xml`, so that would preclude an enclosing tag. His only purpose in trying to use `xinclude` was to insert an xml fragment into a `<logfile>` root element.

Comment: @ekhumoro - exactly, I want be able to append events just by writing to the end of the events.xml file. This way I don't need to parse (& load into memory) the events.xml each time I want to append an event. I could manually write a closing root tag the the events.xml (e.g. </events>) but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: It's not as simple as a file append, but you don't necessarily need to load the whole thing into memory. You can use streaming parsing. See [iterparse and iterwalk](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#iterparse-and-iterwalk).